# Pause in JQuery based on a condition (Waiting for RegisterClientScriptBlock)

Tags: jquery, delay, registerclientscriptblock

I'm trying to get my JQuery to pause until an object has been loaded. I have seen the .delay() function but I don't want to delay a specific object $('item').delay(10) so can I do something like below?

```
while(myObject==null){
  // 1 second wait for ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to finish building Json
  pause(1);
}

DosomethingWithJson();
```

Comment: You cannot "pause" JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: How would you go about waiting for the json object to be populated? It seems to need a fraction of a second before it loads but IE8 intermittently works

Comment: You cannot "wait".  What you **can** do is use a callback passed into an ajax facility to perform some work at such time as a request has been completed. If you're using a script loader, it will provide a facility to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** try this: `myObject.ready();`

Comment: Can you use this on any object: myObject.ready()? I'm waiting for a partial postback to complete so the $(document).ready() would probably be true even if that object has not been created.

Comment: Yes, this is from jQuery documentation: ready()=> _Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded._. so I think you can simply use: myobject.ready() and add the code that you want to execute when this element is fully populated.

Comment: from jQuery official documentation: _In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead._  I highly recommend you to read these few lines in this page: http://api.jquery.com/ready/